# KeyError: '594750729810477063' in discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

```
await open_account(ctx.author)
    users = await get_bank_data()

    earnings = (a_var3)

    users[str(discord.user.id)]["Simp Wallet"] += earnings

@bot.command()
async def balance(ctx):
    await open_account(ctx.author)

    users = await get_bank_data()

    wallet_amt = users[str(user.id)]["Simp Wallet"] = 0
    bank_amt =  users[str(user.id)]["Simp Bank"] = 0


    em = discord.Embed(title = f"{ctx.author.name}'s Balance")
    em.add_field(name = "Simp Wallet", value = wallet_amt)
    em.add_field(name = "Simp Bank", value = bank_amt)
    await ctx.send(embed = em)


async def open_account(user):
    users = await get_bank_data()

    if str(user.id) is users:
        return False
    else:
        users[str(user.id)]["Simp Wallet"] = 0
        users[str(user.id)]["Simp Bank"] = 0

    with open('mainbank.json',"w") as f:
        json.dump(users,f)
    return True

async def get_bank_data():
    with open('mainbank.json',"r") as f:
        users = json.load(f)
    return users
```

discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: KeyError: '594750729810477063'. is what is says.Im not expert at this so, any help would be much appreciated!

Full Traceback below:

```
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 859, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: KeyError: '345878244756684801'
```

Comment: Hey there. What's the full traceback? Python is really good at error messages. It'll tell you exactly what line of your code is the problem, and how we arrived at that line. Without that info it's really hard to know what's going on

Comment: Can you show the full traceback and write what are you trying to do?

Comment: JSON data doesn't allow integers as keys. Perhaps a user ID didn't have a key in your dictionary?

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply... Heres the traceback

`Ignoring exception in command beg:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/bot/vibebot.py", line 86, in beg
    await open_account(ctx.author)
  File "C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/bot/vibebot.py", line 119, in open_account
    users[str(user.id)]["Simp Wallet"] = 0
KeyError: '345878244756684801'`

Comment: your `users` dict does not have a key for user 345878244756684801

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `open_account` function doesn't look like it will do what you need it to do. You need it to create a new account if there isn't one yet, for the given user. But you don't have any code that checks for an existing user (it looks like you were trying, but had a typo), and you don't have code to create the inner dictionary either.

Here's what I think you want:

```
async def open_account(user):
    users = await get_bank_data()

    if str(user.id) in users:                         # note, use "in" here rather than "is"
        return False

    users[str(user.id)] = {"Simp Wallet": 0, "Simp Bank": 0}  # create inner dictionary here

    with open('mainbank.json',"w") as f:
        json.dump(users,f)
    return True
```